# Start service after all custom actions

Tags: wix

We tried ServiceControl Start="install" ...  but service is trying to start before some custom actions. For example deferred CA that installs DB or CA that modifies some file. But it is completely wrong. So, we use CA to start services. Do we do it in a right way?

Answer (score 3):

The [ServiceControl element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd%5Cwix%5Cservicecontrol.html) creates the [ServiceControl tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)le is processed by the [StartServices standard action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You need to look at your built MSI using ORCA and take a look at the InstallExecute sequence.

At a minimum these custom actions need to be scheduled before StartServices.  Otherwise the service would need to be more flexible such as polling for changes to it's config file and reloading and being ok with a database that's not yet available and trying to connect later.